# Windows 7 with static IP | Suddenly stop working Internet connection

Tags: troubleshooting, dns, windows

I have a Windows 7 installation and because I run an Apache web server with Virtual Hosts, I have assign a static IP in my network interface. The given IP is **192.168.1.100**. Suddenly, today, my computer cannot get connected on the internet because of the static IP. If I change the static IP to dynamic IP then i am getting connected to the internet.

Also note, that I run the **Windows Network Diagnostics** and I am getting the following message when I am with static IP:

```
Problems found
Your computer appears to be correctly configures, but the device 
or resource (primary DNS server) is not responding.
```

Can somebody to help me ? Is crucial to me the static IP, because without static IP I cannot run my local based projects.

Kind regards

Comment: Did you set the DNS when you set the static IP?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be about professional network engineering... please see http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd check my default gateway information/DNS information that is working when you switch to DHCP (dynamic), then make sure with your static IP that your gateway/DNS is the same. If you do ipconfig /all when it's working all this information will be shown from the command line.

Based on the error Windows reports, your DNS is not configured correctly. So definitely check what DNS server you're statically assigning. If you want to test your DNS, try pinging www.google.com, does it resolve an IP? Can you ping 8.8.8.8? If you can ping 8.8.8.8 but not www.google.com, it's a DNS configuration problem